# Breaking after finding the kth element of an inorder traversal using a higher order traversal function

Tags: algorithm, haskell, binary-tree

I have the following code to do an inorder traversal of a Binary Tree:

```
data BinaryTree a =
  Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
  | Leaf
  deriving (Show)

inorder :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
inorder f acc tree = go tree acc
  where go Leaf z = z
        go (Node v l r) z = (go r . f v . go l) z
```

Using the inorder function above I'd like to get the kth element without having to traverse the entire list.

The traversal is a little like a fold given that you pass it a function and a starting value. I was thinking that I could solve it by passing `k` as the starting value, and a function that'll decrement `k` until it reaches 0 and at that point returns the value inside the current node.

The problem I have is that I'm not quite sure how to `break` out of the recursion of inorder traversal short of modifying the whole function, but I feel like having to modify the higher order function ruins the point of using a higher order function in the first place.

Is there a way to break after k iterations?

Comment: `take k (inorder f [] tree)`, where `f` is a function that produces a list containing in-order traversal of the tree.

Comment: @chepner I think `inorder` as written will always traverse the entire tree. Obviously it would be desirable to write a "better" `inorder` function which can avoid doing so when its `f` is sufficiently lazy; the question here as I see it is about how.

Comment: @chepner that doesn't break early though. I thought that would work as well and that inorder would evaluate lazily, but it didn't seem to the case when I did `take 1 (inorder (:) [] testTree)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I observe that the results of the recursive call to `go` on the left and right subtrees are not available to `f`; hence no matter what `f` does, it cannot choose to ignore the results of recursive calls. Therefore I believe that `inorder` as written will *always* walk over the entire tree. (**edit**: On review, this statement may be a bit strong; it seems `f` may have a chance to ignore left subtrees. But the point basically stands; there is no reason to elevate left subtrees over right subtrees in this way.)

A better choice is to give the recursive calls to `f`. For example:

```
anyOldOrder :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
anyOldOrder f z = go where
    go Leaf = z
    go (Node v l r) = f v (go l) (go r)
```

Now when we write

```
flatten = anyOldOrder (\v ls rs -> ls ++ [v] ++ rs) []
```

we will find that `flatten` is sufficiently lazy:

```
> take 3 (flatten (Node 'c' (Node 'b' (Node 'a' Leaf Leaf) Leaf) undefined))
"abc"
```

(The `undefined` is used to provide evidence that this part of the tree is never inspected during the traversal.) Hence we may write

```
findK k = take 1 . reverse . take k . flatten
```

which will correctly short-circuit. You can make `flatten` slightly more efficient with the standard [difference list](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list) technique:

```
flatten' t = anyOldOrder (\v l r -> l . (v:) . r) id t []
```

Just for fun, I also want to show how to implement this function without using an accumulator list. Instead, we will produce a stateful computation which walks over the "interesting" part of the tree, stopping when it reaches the `k`th element. The stateful computation looks like this:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

kthElem k v l r = l <|> do
    i <- get
    if i == k
        then return v
        else put (i+1) >> r
```

Looks pretty simple, hey? Now our `findK` function will farm out to `kthElem`, then do some newtype unwrapping:

```
findK' k = (`evalState` 1) . runMaybeT . anyOldOrder (kthElem 3) empty
```

We can verify that it is still as lazy as desired:

```
> findK' 3 $ Node 'c' (Node 'b' (Node 'a' Leaf Leaf) Leaf) undefined
Just 'c'
```

Comment: This, however, is potentially inefficient because left-associated appends can stack up. You can fix that by passing a different `f` (this is basically a catamorphism approach, and likely involves `Endo` in some fashion). Alternatively, and strictly less generally, you can use a `Foldable`-style approach by passing right children down to the left children.

Comment: @dfeuer Updated with an append-less solution using the same `anyOldOrder` function.

Comment: @DanielWagner your edit is way over my head. Anywhere I can go to do more reading on what's actually happening because it does not "look simple" haha.

Comment: @AR7 Yeah, the "looks pretty simple" comment was a bit tongue-in-cheek. =) As for what's actually happening -- perhaps it is best to direct you at [All About Monads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads), which as I recall has an excellent section on the `State` and `Maybe` monads. If you're comfortable with those and still not sure what's going on, please feel free to ask a more precise question and I'll be glad to try to explain or otherwise help you understand.

Comment: @DanielWagner I think I generally do understand monads, but I'd definitely have to do some more reading before asking specifics. I think before I get to that, I'm wondering how the switch to passing f the arguments makes it lazy. Could you explain what exactly about the arguments being passed to f caused the function to switch to being lazy?

Comment: @AR7 With `go (Node v l r) z = go r (f v (go l z))`, the outermost call is a recursive call to `go`, hence has no choice but to recurse (and therefore inspect the subtree and, by induction, every node along the right spine). On the other hand, with `go (Node v l r) = f v (go l) (go r)`, the outermost call is a *non*-recursive call to `f`. This means it is `f` -- and not `go` -- which is driving the evaluation, and may choose how much of the tree to inspect. In particular it may choose not to use the values produced by the recursive calls to `go l` and `go r`, hence never actually compute them.

Comment: @AR7 ...continuing the previous comment, note that in particular with your definition, `go (Node v l r) z = go r (f v (go l z))`, you do still get _some_ laziness available: since the "next outermost" call after `go` is to `f`, it is possible for `f` to ignore left subtrees -- but this is not as general as you really want for many applications.

Comment: @DanielWagner is there any way to make flatten work with `:` instead of `++` I've been trying to think of a way, but none of them have worked.

Comment: @DanielWagner also is there some kind of idiomatic way to do this? I'm just curious if there's a definitive solution that's not based on my original code or what you put in your answer.

Comment: @AR7 Both defining a catamorphism (my `anyOldOrder`) and deriving `Foldable` as in dfeuer's answer are idiomatic. I'm not sure what your question about `:` vs `++` means. And by the way, you absolutely should steal the idea of using [difference lists](https://wiki.haskell.org/Difference_list) instead of plain lists to implement `flatten` (as dfeuer does in his answer) -- I used lists only to make code that was as plain and readable as possible, but he is correct to point out that this sacrifices efficiency.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah well I've just read that you generally want to avoid `++` and use `:` when you can instead for performance reasons, but I when I tried to figure out how to use `:` to put together the list using `anyOldOrder` I wasn't able to do it any way at all.

Comment: @AR7 I have updated my answer to include a comment about using difference lists to implement `flatten`. Perhaps this will address your efficiency concerns.

Comment: @DanielWagner awesome that's exactly what I wanted. I got pretty close to that, but not quite. One last question: what's the point of doing `id t` instead of just `t`? Doesn't that just return `t`?

Comment: @AR7 At no point do I call `id t`! Because it's a nice puzzle and a nice technique that you may enjoy exploring yourself, I'll let you ponder that for a bit and include the spoilers rot13'd: V nz npghnyyl cnffvat `vq` nf gur `m` nethzrag gb `nalByqBeqre`, juvpu vf hfrq gb fgnaq va sbe `Yrns`f. Gur erfhyg bs gur jubyr sbyq vf n shapgvba juvpu gnxrf n yvfg naq cercraqf gur inyhr bs gur va-beqre genirefny gb gung yvfg.

Comment: @DanielWagner ahhhhhhhh it's like a noop because composing id with a list prepend func yields the same list prepend! Much smarter than what I was trying to do. `id . (1:) . id $ [] == (1:) []` :O

Answer (score 4):

There are (at least?) two important generalizations of the notion of *folding* a list. The first, more powerful, notion is that of a *catamorphism*. The `anyOldOrder` of Daniel Wagner's answer follows this pattern.

But for your particular problem, the catamorphism notion is a bit more power than you need. The second, weaker, notion is that of a `Foldable` container. `Foldable` expresses the idea of a container whose elements can all be mashed together using the operation of an arbitrary `Monoid`. Here's a cute trick:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

-- Note that for this trick  only I've 
-- switched the order of the Node fields.
data BinaryTree a =
  Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
  | Leaf
  deriving (Show, Foldable)

index :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
[] `index` _ = Nothing
(x : _) `index` 0 = Just x
(_ : xs) `index` i = xs `index` (i - 1)

(!?) :: Foldable f => Int -> f a -> Maybe a
xs !? i = toList xs `index` i
```

Then you can just use `!?` to index into your tree!

---

That trick is cute, and in fact deriving `Foldable` is a tremendous convenience, but it won't help you understand anything. I'll start by showing how you can define `treeToList` fairly directly and efficiently, without using `Foldable`.

```
treeToList :: BinaryTree a -> [a]
treeToList t = treeToListThen t []
```

The magic is in the `treeToListThen` function. `treeToListThen t more` converts `t` to a list and appends the list `more` to the end of the result. This slight generalization turns out to be all that's required to make conversion to a list efficient.

```
treeToListThen :: BinaryTree a -> [a] -> [a]
treeToListThen Leaf more = more
treeToListThen (Node v l r) more =
  treeToListThen l $ v : treeToListThen r more
```

Instead of producing an inorder traversal of the left subtree and then appending everything else, we tell the left traversal what to stick on the end when it's done! This avoids the potentially serious inefficiency of repeated list concatenation that can turn things O(n^2) in bad cases.

Getting back to the `Foldable` notion, turning things into lists is a special case of `foldr`:

```
toList = foldr (:) []
```

So how can we implement `foldr` for trees? It ends up being somewhat similar to what we did with `toList`:

```
foldrTree :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> BinaryTree a -> b
foldrTree _ n Leaf = n
foldrTree c n (Node v l r) = foldrTree c rest l
  where
    rest = v `c` foldrTree c n r
```

That is, when we go down the left side, we tell it that when it's done, it should deal with the current node and its right child.

Now `foldr` isn't quite the most fundamental operation of `Foldable`; that is actually

```
foldMap :: (Foldable f, Monoid m)
        => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

It is possible to implement `foldr` using `foldMap`, in a somewhat tricky fashion using a peculiar `Monoid`. I don't want to overload you with details of that right now, unless you ask (but you should look at the default definition of `foldr` in `Data.Foldable`). Instead, I'll show how `foldMap` can be defined using Daniel Wagner's `anyOldOrder`:

```
instance Foldable BinaryTree where
  foldMap f = anyOldOrder bin mempty where
    bin lres v rres = lres <> f v <> rres
```

Comment: @dfeur doesn't "treeToListThen" need to traverse the entire tree?

Comment: It lazily constructs a list from left, you can stop producing new elements whenever you want, which means you have only traversed to the node that produced the last element you need and the call to `treeToListThen r more` is still pending. You have only collected "stubs" (or "promises") for all the right branches (and parents), which you then choose not to evaluate, i.e. recurse into.

Comment: So, for posterity: I at first wanted to object that `treeToListThen` always recurses on its left branch and therefore forces the left spine of any node it visits (and therefore might reasonably be called less lazy than the catamorphism-based approach). However, after some more thought, it turns out this is no objection:  if we want the `k`th node from an inorder traversal, we have no choice but to lose at least that much laziness, no matter what implementation technique we choose.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the only way to fix that is to annotate nodes with their sizes.